# Log4net doesn't log online

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, log4net

I'm trying to use log4net to log errors on my MVC 4 website. It works fine offline, but when we publish the website, log4net doesn't even create the log file.

Here is the Web.config code:

```
  <log4net>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="mylog.txt"/> 
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <header value="**"/>
        <footer value="**"/>
        <conversionPattern value="%newline%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

I added this to the Assembly:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

Here is my code to call the logger:

```
public void logInfo(string message)
{
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    logger.Info(message);
}
```

Comment: does the web application pool have write permission to the folder the file is being output to?

Comment: How do I check if it has write permission?

Comment: Get the user identity of the web application pool from IIS (if this is shared hosting not sure how you get this).  See if the identity of the application pool has write permissions on the folder you're trying to log to.

Answer (score 0):

This is bcoz,the root folder doesn't have write permissions where you are trying to create the log file.

steps to provide write permissions:
1) right click on "folder"
2) go to properties
3) click on security
4) Click on add-> add everyone-> check on full control.
it will work fine now.